# Android FacebookActivity doesn't show Cannot call determinedVisibility()

Tags: android, android-studio, facebook-sdk-4.0

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register_rs1);
        //String username = getIntent().getExtras().getString("username");
        //Log.w("username is",username);

        loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);


        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                // App code
                Log.d("FACEBOOK", "SUCCESS");
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                // App code
                Log.d("FACEBOOK", "CANCEL");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                // App code
                Log.d("FACEBOOK", "ERROR"+exception.toString());
            }
        });
        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
                new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                        // App code
                        Log.d("FACEBOOK MANAGER", "SUCCESS");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        // App code
                        Log.d("FACEBOOK MANAGER", "CANCEL");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                        // App code
                        Log.d("FACEBOOK MANAGER", "ERROR");
                    }
                });
```

i use this code to Login with facebook and when i press to the facebook login button .. it's just stay loading and the FacebookActivity never show..

this is my logcat screen:
W/BindingManager: Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 8328

Comment: Same thing happening with me, any solutions yet?

Comment: This is happening as well to several of my coworkers using SDK 4.18 and now 4.19. After pressing the login button a spinner will show and sit there for a LONG time (typically 30 seconds or longer).. eventually the app will get logged-in. The strange thing is - I couldn't reproduce using 3 different devices (S4, S5 and S7) all running different OS's.

I also see a similar warning in the log:

`Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 22366`

Answer (score 0):

I opened an issue with Facebook for this problem - or at least what I think is the same issue.. basically in my case the login process is very slow and seems to hang for some users/devices.

If anyone has a similar issue can you add additional details to the bug below so we can get someone at FB to investigate?

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/264734493940722/